# SQL Using specific input find corresponding columns and create new summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, lateral-join

Data is a flat normalised table:

```
|ID     |   Product selected    |   Product Code 1  |   Product Code 2  |   Product Code 3  | Cost of Product 1 | Cost of Product 2 | Cost of Product 3 | Rate of Product 1 | Rate of Product 2 | Rate of Product 3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1      |       ABCDEDFHIJKL    |   AAABBBCCCDDD    |   ABCDEDFHIJKL    |   DDDCCCBBBAAA    |       995         |       495         |       0           |       4.4         |       6.3         |       7.8         |
|2      |       DDDCCCBBBAAA    |   AAABBBCCCDDD    |   ABCDEDFHIJKL    |   DDDCCCBBBAAA    |       995         |       495         |       0           |       4.4         |       6.3         |       7.8         |
```

What:

Using the product selected (ABCDEDFHIJKL), look across the rows to find the corresponding locations of columns with data relating to the product selected.

Desired Output:

```
|   Product selected    | Cost of Product   | Rate of Product   | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       ABCDEDFHIJKL    |       495         |       6.3         |
|       DDDCCCBBBAAA    |       0           |       7.8         |
```

To do this in R is straight forward, and i'm sure for someone more knowledgable in SQL than I, this will be easy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
select t.product_selected, x.cost_of_product, x.rate_of_product
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (product_code_1, cost_of_product_1, rate_of_product_1),
    (product_code_2, cost_of_product_2, rate_of_product_2),
    (product_code_3, cost_of_product_3, rate_of_product_3)
) as x(product_selected, cost_of_product, rate_of_product)
where x.product_selected = t.product_selected
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for coming back with an answer, i'm having some difficulty (could be due to me using SAP SyBase IQ), but it doesn't appear to like the 'values' function...

Comment: @Laurie7: you tagged your question SQL Server, so that's an answer for SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

Either use unpivot or union or crossapply

Unpivot sample

```
SELECT [Product selected], ProductCode ,ProductCost,ProductRate 
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.table
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  ProductCode FOR PC IN ([Product Code 1], [Product Code 2], [Product Code 3])
) AS up

   UNPIVOT 
    (
      ProductCost FOR Po IN ([Cost of Product 1], [Cost of Product 2], [Cost of Product 3])
) AS up2

   UNPIVOT 
    (
  ProductRate FOR Pr  IN ([Rate of Product 1], [Rate of Product 2], [Rate of Product 3])
) AS up3;
```